# Membership check of items in both dict and list, in nested for-loops, without using sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an ordered dict:

```
import collections  
collections.OrderedDict([('key', {'keyword': {'blue', 'yellow'}}), ('key1', {'keyword': {'lock', 'door'}})])
```

and list of `potential_matches`: `[red, blue, one]`

I want to order these potential matches into one of two lists:
`correct = []` or `incorrect = []`

If the potential match is a keyword of one of the keys in the dict, then it goes in `correct`, else it goes in `incorrect`.

Result of this example should be:
`correct = [blue]`, `incorrect = [red, one]`

Here is what I tried:

```
correct = []  
incorrect = []  
for word in potential_matches:
    for key, value in ordered_dict.items():
        if word in value["keyword"] and word not in correct:
            correct.append(word)
        elif word not in value["keyword"] and word not in correct and word not in incorrect:
            incorrect.append(word)
```

Essentially, all remaining words that are not a match should simply go to the other list.

Though it works, doesn't seem efficient. It must be a list to preserve order, and lists may overlap.

Note: I asked a similar question previously although in that case the situation and answer called for the use of a python set, as items were unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v=[x for i in od.values() for x in list(i.values())[0]]
l=['red','blue','one']
correct=[i for i in v if i in l]
incorrect=[i for i in l if i not in v]
print(correct)
print(incorrect)
```

Output:

```
['blue']
['red', 'one']
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get values from your `OrderedDict`, then you can use simple list comprehension to get the values. To get the values you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) along with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). This will give you a flat list of values.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> values = list(chain(*map(itemgetter('keyword'), list(d.values()))))
>>> values
>>> ['yellow', 'blue', 'lock', 'door']
>>> m = ['red', 'blue', 'one']

>>> correct = [s for s in m if s in values]
>>> correct
>>> ['blue']

>>> incorrect = [a for a in m if a not in values]
>>> incorrect
>>> ['red', 'one']
```

Comment: What are the advantages or important differences btwn this method and the other answer?

Comment: The only difference is to fetch list of values. The `timeit` stats is almost the same `~1.4 uses per loop` for both solution . My solution uses a key `keyword` to fetch the values of nested dict, where as the above solution uses index `0` to be fixed for key `keyword`. Also if you are open to use `sets` to instead of list it will give you a performance increase.